# Insert fraction as text to Excel with Aspose library

Tags: java, excel, aspose

I need to generate column where some values are fractions. In this case Excel display this value as calculated value or even as a date(for preparing screenshot I manually added space).

I see the solution as applying function:

> =TEXT(value, \"0/#0\")

So, my question is how to apply function to cell using java Aspose library? Does it is the best solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is MS Excel's behavior which converts the fraction values to DateTime or numeric (calculated) values. You may easily cope with it via applying numbers formatting to your specified cells. See the sample code with comments for your reference on how to display fraction values in the cells using Aspose.Cells for Java. Also, see the code on how to apply formula to cells:
e.g
**Sample code:**

```
 Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
//Get the first worksheet (default sheet)    
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);
Cells cells = worksheet.getCells();

//Input fraction values to the cells.
Cell cell1 = cells.get("A1");
double val1 = 1/2d;
cell1.putValue(val1);

Cell cell2 = cells.get("A2");
double val2 = 19/4d;
cell2.putValue(val2);

Cell cell3 = cells.get("A3");
double val3 = 5/3d;
cell3.putValue(val3);


//Create a style object.
Style style = workbook.createStyle();
//Set the numbers formatting
style.setCustom("# ?/?");

//Apply style to the cells.
cell1.setStyle(style);
cell2.setStyle(style);
cell3.setStyle(style);


//Apply formula to a cell
Cell cell4 = cells.get("B1");
cell4.setFormula("=TEXT(A1,\"0/#0\")");

//Even you may directly put numeric value as text value.
Cell cell5 = cells.get("C1");
cell5.putValue("1/2", false);
//Note: if you double cliked in the cell, it will be converted to numeric DateTime notations.


//Save the file
workbook.save("f:\\files\\out1.xls");
```

Note: I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Actually I have an issue with this approaches.

`double val3 = 5/3d;
cell3.putValue(val3);`

Comment: what is the issue you find, kindly elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, I did not finish comment. Actually I decided to use this approach `cell5.putValue("1/2", false);`  and works for me so far. Thanks a lot

Comment: Good to know that your have sorted it out and you are welcome.